# Simple question on the unitary representation.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3$ are all irreducible, unitary representation of some algebraic group G.

Then is it ture that $$Hom_{G}(\pi_1,\pi_2 \otimes \pi_3) \simeq Hom_{G}(\pi_1 \otimes (\pi_2)^{\vee},\pi_3)?$$

Here, $\pi_2 \otimes \pi_3$ and $\pi_1 \otimes (\pi_2)^{\vee}$ are repsentation of $G$ via diagoanl embedding $i:G \to G \times G$ and $^{\vee}$ denote its contragredient representation.

I think that it would ture and I constructed the homomorphism $$H:Hom_{G}(\pi_1,\pi_2 \otimes \pi_3) \to Hom_{G}(\pi_1 \otimes (\pi_2)^{\vee},\pi_3)$$ defined as follows:

For $g\in Hom_{G}(\pi_1,\pi_2 \otimes \pi_3)$, $v_1 \in \pi_1$, $w_2 \in \pi_2^{\vee}$

$H(g)(v_1,w_2):=w_2(g(v_1))$ letting $w_2$ acts as identity on $\pi_3$ components.

I think this should be isomorphism but cannot prove it. Is this an isomorphism?

Comment: This is an isomorphism if the representation is finite dimensional (this adjunction actually holds in any rigid tensor category if these words make any sense to you). The inverse map is as follows:

Given $\phi : Hom_{G}(\pi_{1} \otimes \pi_{2}^{\vee}, \pi_{3})$ and $v \in \pi_{1}$, pick some basis $\{w_{1}, \ldots, w_{n}\}$ for $\pi_{2}$, and then do

$$\sum_{i} \phi(v \otimes w_{i}^{*}) \otimes w_{i}.$$

This is actually canonical because all I've done is write the identity morphism from $\pi_{2} \rightarrow \pi_{2}$ as an element of $\pi_{2}^{\vee} \otimes \pi_{2}.$

Comment: @Siddharth Venkatesh, Thank yoy for your illumination. It seems to hold in finite dimesional representations. Indeed, I am reading some paper and the author of the paper used the above formula for irreducible admissible infinite dimensional representations. Thus I guess it will also hold for infinite dimensional representations. As the author the above formula, he stressed that given representations are all unitary. Does unitary condition make them ture even in infinite dimension?

Comment: I haven't done much with unitary infinite dimensional representations but I imagine that the result will hold in the unitary infinite case if you define your contragredient representations carefully enough. Basically the main problem in that cast is that the standard dual is too big.

Comment: You are right. I forgot the condition that the given representation is admissible.

There is a notion of contragredient infinite dimensional representation associated to this notion of admissibility. 
Let $G$ be a totally disconencted locally compact group.
If $V$ is an admissible representation of $G$, its contragredient representation $V^{\vee}$ is the subspace of $\bar{V}$, which is an algebraic dual of $V$, such that invariant by some open subgroup in $G$. Then $V^{\vee}$ can be decomposed as the direct sum of finite-dimensional representations and so we can apply your above remark.

Comment: But I am still wondering why the author has emphasized the unitarycity of the representations.